# Scala- Some bytes are missing because of 'hasNext' function?

Tags: scala

Listing below is my code:

```
import scala.io.Source
object grouped_list {

  def encrypt(file: String) = {
    val text = Source.fromFile(file)
    val list = text.toList
    val blocks = list.grouped(501)

    while (blocks.hasNext) {
      val block0 = blocks.next()
      val stringBlock = block0.mkString
      println(stringBlock)
    }
  }

  def main (args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val blockcipher = encrypt("E:\\test.txt")
}
```

The file ("E:\test.txt", https://pan.baidu.com/s/1jHKuWb8) is about 300KB, however, the 'stringBlock' (https://pan.baidu.com/s/1pLygsyR) which is supposed to be the same with the file is about only 80KB, where are the rest? When I am not doing the 'while(blocks.hasNext)', the first 501 bytes of 'stringBlock' is the same with the file's first 501 bytes. After I did the 'while(blocks.hasNext)' ,  the first 501 bytes of 'stringBlock' is no longer the same with the file's. Is my problem has something to do with the 'hasNext' function?

Comment: I tried your code with a long text file, and ran the output through diff.  It does change the file, but only slightly.  In particular, the code above will add a line break after every block.   I saw no deletion of early material.  As far as I can tell from reading the scala api doc this code is using `hasNext`/`next` correctly and is not dropping input.

Comment: If you want more people to help you, I suggest experimenting until you discover a shorter file that is mangled by the above code, and posting that input file, the output you received, and what you wanted to receive.  Questions like these need a good test case but without `test.txt` and your output people can only guess.  Also, the code needed `import scala.io.Source` at the top.

Comment: You are using `println`. How are you capturing the output? My experience is some IDEs may drop some console output when overloaded.

Comment: Try printing the output to a new file and compare it with the original one: `val pw = new PrintWriter(new File("test0.txt")); while (blocks.hasNext){ pw.write(stringBlock) }; pw.close;`

Comment: @Suma What is your suggestion of capturing the output?

Comment: @Jason See my comment.

Comment: @FedericoPellegatta I have tried it.Your answer can successfully print the output to a new file. I would like to try to print it on the screen.

Comment: @JasonShu Can you answer first, please? How are you capturing the output now? Are you running in some IDE, or command line? If command line what OS?